# Why do i need to use a cache server even though DBMS has its own cache?

Tags: mysql, database, caching, memcached, mediawiki

I recently got acquainted with memcached. That made some serious questions for me.
Suppose i have a news web application. Obviously most costly job is to send prepared queries to fetch any news content from the database. 
By assuming that database itself caches news contents as well as query plans, what's the benefits of using separate cache servers?

**More details of application (imaginary):**

- Database size is more than 300GB (preferably MySQL or any other DBMS)
- RAM memory is 32GB
- Database may or may not resides in webserver

=== in case of using cache servers ===

- Three servers each of which with 32GB memory

I know that cache servers like memcached, virtually make it seem like you have a 96GB aggregated cache. But on the other hand there should be at least some extra requests from the webserver land to the cacheserver land.

My understanding of the path every request made by clients needs to go through, is like so:

**If using cache servers:**

web server => cache server == does data exist inside the cache server? =>

1. YES => webserver => client
2. NO  => DB server => web server => client; also a save request to the
   cache server

**If not using cache servers:**

web server => DB server => webserver => client

And also what if both web server and DB server are serverd in same computer? So that we will have this:
web server => client

**So my main questions are:**

- Is it worth to make extra requests from web server to other servers
  rather than making a single request to our DB?
- Have i missed something here?
- Are there any other solutions? What approach do big systems like wikipedia use in this specific issue and caching?
- Can we use another approach like using any special caching system
  bond to the DBMS, each server keeping database but only caching a
  fraction of it in memory. This way not only we can use other servers
  for high availability and replication purpose but we can reduce count
  of requests.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, A cache is used to increase the performance of a system. Difference between the cache and the database is mostly the
  data stored in the database is persisted to the disk, while as in cache it's get stored into the RAM. because accessing the data from RAM is faster than accessing from Disk.
- Some database like MySQL comes with cache inbuilt but it also has few problems like where data stored into the MySQL cache will be get removed automatically if you make any updates to table like insert, delete and update.
- It's also not needed to keep a different server for a cache if you're going to cache only few MB's of data. some cache system's like Memcached and Redis you can like the memory size to allocate for the cache. if cache reached the memory limit the already existing data will be removed based on the eviction policy we configured. Plus We use cache not only to cache the DB query results, but we can also cache some use configuration settings instead of reading it from the file every time.

Comment: This is a very general answer. upvoting it... Also will get accepted if you focus on my questions

Comment: It seems that new users are not allowed to upvote questions!